# ImportError: No module named expected_conditions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Linux Mint 17 and python 2.7 and selenium. 
When I try to selenium webdriver its working fine 
but python not detecting expected_conditions

```
    >>import selenium
    >>import expected_conditions as EC
     Trackback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>        
ImportError: No module named expected_conditions
```

any solution to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you want to import Selenium's expected conditions

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Have you installed Selenium? Can you launch a browser after importing selenium webdriver?

Comment: @user2731159 what selenium version are you using? Do you have a file named `selenium.py`?

Comment: Selenium installed & Browser=Chrome tested working fine @Amey